# Empty smarty variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty

Why smarty variable doesn't have value in my code when I tested on /nl/nl/ address?

Code:

```
{php}
  global $country; global $lang;
  $this->assign('curLang',$lang);
  $this->assign('curCountry',$country);
{/php}
{if $curLang == "nl" && ($curCountry == "nl" || $curCountry == "be")}
  {literal}
   javascript code
  {/literal}
  {assign name="test" value="1"}
{/if}
{$curCountry} <!-- nl -->
{$curLang} <!-- nl -->
{$test} <!-- Empty value  -->
```

Comment: Maybe your if statement is not being executed...

Comment: @GytisŠk I edited my post. Strange behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{assign name="test" value="1"}
```

nope,

```
{assign var="test" value="1"}

{$test}
```

Use name= like this http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

Comment: Thank you very much It should be var instead of name

Comment: Thks for the vote, shorthand {assign 'test' 1} is even easier to remember, depends on if you find that easier to consume and figure out when you get back though.